# Per project flake8 configuration

Tags: vim, syntastic, flake8

I'm using flake8 through syntastic in vim and I want a configuration file per project.

On the [syntastic documentation](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/wiki/Configuration-Files) it states that:

> Depending on the checker, the filename of the corresponding
>   configuration file can be specified by setting either
>   `g:syntastic_<filetype>_checker_file` or
>   `g:syntastic_<checker>_config_file`. See the checker's documentation in
>   the wiki for the exact name.

The [flake8 documentation](http://flake8.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html) says that `.flake8` is a valid configuration file name. So I tried to place a valid flake8-configuration file called `.flake8` in the root folder of my project. No luck.

I've also tried setting `g:syntastic_flake8_config_file` and `g:syntastic_python_checker_file` to `.flake8` in my `~/.vimrc`, still nothing.

What am I missing?

Comment: You have given the same thing twice(g:syntastic__config_file). Edit the question correctly)

Comment: I don't know about flake8. But FileType and extension are different. Open any .flake8 file and type :set filetype in command line. The result will be its FileType. Now, you can use that in g:syntastic_<FileType>_checker_file. It will work.

Comment: You're reading the docs out of context and you're getting confused as a result.  Syntastic config files apply only to __some__ checkers, mainly for C and C++.  The list is given at the beginning of the file you quoted, and it doesn't include either `flake8`, or `python`.  On the other hand, the Python script `flake8` has its own config files, that have nothing to do with syntastic.  Start by reading`:h filetype` and find out what Vim filetypes are. Then read `:h syntastic`, and make sure you understand the difference between syntastic checkers and external binaries or scripts.

Answer (score 4):

Just adding a .flake8 file to my working directory didn't work for me either.

But you can pass commandline options to syntastic checkers by setting the following option in your .vimrc:

`let g:syntastic_LANGUAGE_CHECKER_args = 'ARGUMENT'`

Flake8 accepts a `--config=PATH` flag to specify a config file, so in your case this would be:

`let g:syntastic_python_flake8_args = '--config=PATH_TO_FLAKE8_CONFIG_FILE'`